# Making Logo as Welcome Header in Neat Theme in Bigcartel

Tags: themes, bigcartel

I am currently working on customizing the welcome page for my Bigcartel site.

I am using the Neat theme and would like to add my logo as the welcome header that appears over the slideshow, instead of just having the standard text.

The problem I am having is when I enter the code for the image, it either erases the slideshow or gives me the image with the header text still appearing.

Answer (score 0):

To replace the Home page welcome text with your uploaded header image, head to **Customize Design > Advanced > Home** then find the following code:

```
  {% if theme.welcome_header != blank or theme.welcome_subheader != blank %}
  <div class="featured_holder">
    <div class="featured">
      {% if theme.welcome_subheader != blank %}<p>{{ theme.welcome_subheader }}</p>{% endif %}
      {% if theme.welcome_header != blank %}<h2>{{ theme.welcome_header }}</h2>{% endif %}
      <a href="/products" class="button">Shop Now</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  {% endif %}
```

Remove that block, and replace it with the following:

```
<div class="featured_holder">
  <div class="featured">
    <img src="{{ theme.logo.url | constrain: '400' }}" alt="{{ store.name }}">
  </div>
</div>
```